# Saving a whole plot in rxplot

Tags: ros, rxplot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to ask anyone who knows any possibility that I can save a full/whole shot of the plot in *rxplot*. Any command line is also okay(any will do). At the moment, I only know that I can save the current plot/window, it's a kind of screen shot. If there is one, it will be cool.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12566/saving-a-whole-plot-in-rxplot/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-01-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-09**:
Yes, exactly! I need the entire figure of it(.PNG will do). How do I achieve that?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-01-09**:
Are you looking for something that can save a .PNG of the entire figure or more like saving a MATLAB .fig file, where you can reopen it and interact with the plot (e.g. zooming, panning, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're probably best off recording the topic to a bag file, then using rxbag to plot the data instead.  rxbag is great on zooming in/out of data, which should give you the functionality you need.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-10**:
Does rxbag has such a functionality to save the entire figure of a graph? And is it be able to plot 2 plots from different topic to be plotted on a single coordinate?